# Simplifying an if-statment

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a program with a few `if`-statements similar to the one I'm about to present to you. I was wondering if you guys could help me simplify this equation in any way. The reason why I ask is because in my Notepad++, it continues on for 443 columns and it's just really frustrating to edit if needed, and just keeps getting longer as I keep adding variables. Basically, for this example of one of my many similar `if` statements, I just want to do an action when ANY of my `SliderBars` try to raise in value when an `int` (`rpg.StatisticPoints`) is equal to, or less then 0. The method I'm using to find out if the sliders are rising in value is to just compare its current value to an `int` associated with the slider, and check if the result is positive.

```
if (rpg.StatisticPoints <= 0 && 
((rpg.WillSlider.getValue() - rpg.Will) < 0) &&
((rpg.PerceptionSlider.getValue() - rpg.Perception) < 0) && 
((rpg.StrengthSlider.getValue() - rpg.Strength) < 0) && 
((rpg.DexteritySlider.getValue() - rpg.Dexterity) < 0) && 
((rpg.ConstitutionSlider.getValue() - rpg.Constitution) < 0) && 
((rpg.CharismaSlider.getValue() - rpg.Charisma) < 0) && 
((rpg.IntelligenceSlider.getValue() - rpg.Intelligence) < 0))
{
//Do actions
}
```

I understand there are a lot of variables here you're not familiar with because you didn't see my full code, but my full source is 100's of lines long and my question is just based on logistics, and not really issues with the syntax.

Comment: Just break the line at each `&&` operator. Alternatively, write a method that checks this condition if it needs to be done often.

Comment: an IDE like intelliJ will auto format many of this

Comment: If you have to check for 443 [!!!] conditions, _maybe_ you have a design flaw in your project.

Comment: `((a - b) < 0)` is usually the same as `a < b`, but not always. Is there a particular reason why you had to do it the first way?

Comment: Can you create a class with two data members - test, limit. Store each pair in an arraylist, then loop through the array doing the compare on the value pairs? More code, but maybe more readable?

Comment: There is a problem with your Architecture. Structure it and iterate the condition over every classes.

Comment: @ moonwave99 : Not that bad. It is 443 columns

Comment: @Tom Thanks! That seems like a really useful way to organize! I'll give it a shot if the community doesn't see something more simple in here

Comment: @moonwave99 I have a lot of variables in this large project im working on

Comment: @harold I did it this way because I clearly wasnt thikning, in addition to Tom's idea, I can use yours of (a < b)  Thanks!

Comment: if you're using Eclipse, hit `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F` and it auto formats the code. i don't know the shortcut in IntelliJ

Comment: @harold: in which case is it any different?

Comment: @JeffRSon `a = 0x7fffffff, b = -1` for example, and other cases where the subtraction overflows.

Comment: @harold: Ah, okay - I would've neglected this for slider values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem with your current solution isn't just a long line, is that it's hard for someone to read and understand what is actually being validated.

Instead of using all the conditions in an `if` statement, you can create an auxiliary method that build the `boolean` value of that validation, and at the same time give it a meaningful name.

For instance:

```
private boolean isValidSomething(){

    boolean result = firstCondition;
    result &= secondCondition;
    ...

    return result;

}
```

This way all your checks will be concentrated in one place, AND it will be a lot more readable, since your `if` will become:

```
 if(isValidSomething()) {...}
```

Of course, create the method with a name that makes sense in your application.

In case you're validating several different conditions that make sense to be separated, go the extra mile and factor them out in to their own methods.

The main thing is to break that logic into pieces that make sense together, like:

```
private boolean validStatistics() {
     return statistics > 0;
}


private boolean validWill() {
     return will > 0;
}

....
```

And your main validation would be something like:

```
private boolean validCharacter() {
     boolean valid = validStatistics();
     valid &= validWill();
     ...
     return valid;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `result = result && secondCondition`, you could write `result &= secondCondition;`

Comment: I know, I wrote it like that first, but thought this would be simpler. But it's just a matter of taste I guess. Edited :)

Comment: i like your answer... readability almost beats every other requirement

Comment: What if he adds a huge number of variables ? What if only checking one conditions amongst the other is sufficient ?

Comment: @ZouZou oh didn't know there was a compound assignment for `&` and `|`, thank you!

Comment: @Xaltar Probably those variables will have a context that depends on the logic, so they should be added to the methods where they make sense.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was never aware that I could write a formula for a `boolean`, and then ask `if (myBoolean == true){//actions}` or `if (myBoolean == false){//do actions}`

Comment: @user2388169 You don't need the `== true` and ` == false` parts, since `myBoolean` is already a boolean expression ;)

Comment: @pcalcao But isn't a `boolean` variable either a `true` or `false` result? if I say `if (myBoolean){//do actions}` would the `if` statement only execute if `myBoolean` is `true`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Test it out :)

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
if (rpg.StatisticPoints <= 0 &&
   (rpg.WillSlider.getValue() < rpg.Will) &&
   (rpg.PerceptionSlider.getValue() < rpg.Perception) &&
   (rpg.StrengthSlider.getValue() <  rpg.Strength) &&
   (rpg.DexteritySlider.getValue() < rpg.Dexterity) &&
   (rpg.ConstitutionSlider.getValue() < rpg.Constitution) &&
   (rpg.CharismaSlider.getValue() < rpg.Charisma) &&
   (rpg.IntelligenceSlider.getValue() < rpg.Intelligence))
{
  //Do actions
}
```

Furthermore, you could move some code to a seperate function:

```
bool CheckSliderValue(TypeOfSlider slider, TypeOfSliderValue value)
{
   return slider.getValue() < value;
}
```

and call this by `CheckSliderValue(rpg.WillSlider, rpg.Will)` a.s.o. Such you could extent the check with a minimum value or easily change "<" to "<=" or alike.

Comment: Thanks, everyone seems to be suggesting the linebreak. I was never away I could break a link in an `if` statement and the compiler would understand it.

Comment: @user2388169 usually if you can put whitespace somewhere, that space is allowed to be arbitrarily large and may include linebreaks and comments etc. You can really mess up the formatting and the compiler won't care. This is not true for all languages.

Answer (score 3):

You can create new variables like:

```
int will = rpg.WillSlider.getValue() - rpg.Will;
```

Then your test will be shorter:

```
if ( ( rpg.StatisticPoints <= 0 ) && ( will < 0 ) && ( Perception < 0 )  ... ) {}
```

Also you can separate test to the new lines:

```
if ( ( rpg.StatisticPoints <= 0 )
  && ( will < 0 )
  && ( perception < 0 )  ... ) {}
```

Comment: maybe even easier, if he adds boolean values already like `boolean hasCharisma` ;)

Comment: Sure thing, everything depends on his idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove most of the `()`s:

```
rpg.StatisticPoints <= 0 &&
rpg.WillSlider.getValue() - rpg.Will < 0 &&
rpg.PerceptionSlider.getValue() - rpg.Perception < 0 &&
rpg.StrengthSlider.getValue() - rpg.Strength < 0 &&
rpg.DexteritySlider.getValue() - rpg.Dexterity < 0 &&
rpg.ConstitutionSlider.getValue() - rpg.Constitution < 0 &&
rpg.CharismaSlider.getValue() - rpg.Charisma < 0 &&
rpg.IntelligenceSlider.getValue() - rpg.Intelligence < 0
```

**Edit**

See the Java Tutorial about [Operator Precendce](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: Thanks, everyone seems to be suggesting the linebreak. I was never away I could break a link in an `if` statement and the compiler would understand it.

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out that I can remove some of these `()` I just thought I'd have to tell the program to make sure you check (rpg.WillSlider.getValue() - rpg.Will < 0) individually before doing actions

Answer (score 2):

```
if (rpg.StatisticPoints <= 0 
    && ((rpg.WillSlider.getValue() - rpg.Will) < 0)
    && ((rpg.PerceptionSlider.getValue() - rpg.Perception) < 0)
    && ((rpg.StrengthSlider.getValue() - rpg.Strength) < 0) 
    && ((rpg.DexteritySlider.getValue() - rpg.Dexterity) < 0) 
    && ((rpg.ConstitutionSlider.getValue() - rpg.Constitution) < 0)
    && ((rpg.CharismaSlider.getValue() - rpg.Charisma) < 0)
    && ((rpg.IntelligenceSlider.getValue() - rpg.Intelligence) < 0)){
    //Do actions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean state= (rpg.StatisticPoints <= 0 && ((rpg.WillSlider.getValue() - rpg.Will) < 0) && ((rpg.PerceptionSlider.getValue() - rpg.Perception) < 0) && ((rpg.StrengthSlider.getValue() - rpg.Strength) < 0) && ((rpg.DexteritySlider.getValue() - rpg.Dexterity) < 0) && ((rpg.ConstitutionSlider.getValue() - rpg.Constitution) < 0) && ((rpg.CharismaSlider.getValue() - rpg.Charisma) < 0) && ((rpg.IntelligenceSlider.getValue() - rpg.Intelligence) < 0));


if(state){/*do actions*/}
```

or

```
 s1=(rpg.StatisticPoints <= 0);
 s2=((rpg.WillSlider.getValue() - rpg.Will) < 0);
 ...
 ...

 if(s1&&s2&&s3...){/* work*/}
```

Comment: This seems really helpful for my current project. For this particular statement, and future statements, Thank you for broadening my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need more than just "inlining" the conditions.
Somewhere, usual programming isn't the right thing to do in your case.

Maybe you could use the `Observer pattern`. If you structure well your classes and add a signal that will raise a flag. For exemple : `One of the condition is false`.

This will be brought back to your main conditions which will check if one flag is ever raised by the `Observer pattern`.

Check about the `Observer pattern`. If your project is going to be huge, I think this could help a lot.

If you only add one variable, then you will only need to write the condition for the new one in a very simple way.